# Redirect to locale with Nuxtjs and i18n on SPA mode

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-i18n, nuxt-i18n

When I generate Nuxtjs on SPA mode (SSR: false) nuxt generated dist without index.html file.

So I have two problems

**1st: I need to redirect to lang folder ex. exmple.com redirect to exmaple.com/{locale}**

**2nd: I need to redirect for sub-pages ex. exmple.com/admin redirect to exmaple.com/{locale}/admin**

```
// nuxt.config.js
...
  i18n: {
    lazy: true,
    langDir: 'lang/',
    locales: [
      {
        code: 'en',
        iso: 'en-US',
        file: 'en.js',
        name: 'English'
      },
      {
        code: 'ar',
        iso: 'ar-EG',
        file: 'ar.js',
        name: 'عربى'
      }
    ],
    defaultLocale: {
      locale: 'en',
      prefix: true
    },
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I got an idea to solve this problem but I did not know if it is the best solution.

Just using `.htaccess` to handle requests and return which index I need.